# How to add a Request Authorization Header using vanilla js for FastAPI and Jinja2 SSR and honoring the user-initiated top-level navigation

Tags: javascript, jinja2, fastapi, server-side-rendering

I was able to add Request Authorization Header using vanilla js fetch but FastAPI HTMLResponse is treated as text not a navigation object. With fetch the Request Header Sec-fetch-dest is "empty" it  should be "document". I tried changing Sec-fetch-dest to "document" but the Browser restores it back to "empty".

Clicking on `<a href="/private">I am in Public. Click to go to Private</a>` should take me to private page.
There are no errors. The response is a text/html but there is no page change.

Is there another way to add Request Authorization Header using vanilla js without resorting to Browser extension interceptors?

main.py

```
    from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Depends  
    from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates  
    from fastapi.security import OAuth2PasswordBearer, OAuth2PasswordRequestForm  
    from typing import Dict  
  
    templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="")  
    app = FastAPI()  
  
    oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="token")  
  
    def get_current_user(token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme)):  
        return dict(id=1, name="george")  
  
    @app.post("/token")  
    def get_access_token(request: Request,
                         form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()):  
        return dict(access_token="gvv", token_type="bearer")  
  
    @app.get("/")  
    def public_page(request: Request):  
        return templates.TemplateResponse("public.html", {"request": request})  
  
    @app.get("/private")  
    def private_page(request: Request,  
                     current_user: Dict = Depends(get_current_user)):  
        return templates.TemplateResponse("private.html", {"request": request})
```

base.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>  
    <html lang="en">  
       <head>  
          <meta charset="UTF-8">  
          <title>Test</title>  
      </head>  
      <body>  
         {% block content %}  
         {% endblock %}  
      </body>  
    </html>
```

public.html

```
    {% extends "./base.html" %}  
    {% block content %}  
      <a href="/private">I am in Public. Click to go to Private</a>  
  
      <script>  
        const element = document.querySelector("a");  
        element.addEventListener('click', (event) => {  
            event.preventDefault();  
            const url = event.target.getAttribute('href');  
            const options = {  
                method: "GET",  
                headers: {  
                    "Authorization": "bearer gvv"  
                }  
            };  
            return fetch(url, options);  
        });  
      </script>  
    {% endblock %}
```

private.html

```
    {% extends "./base.html" %}  
    {% block content %}  
       <a href="/">I am in Private. Click to go to Public</a>  
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: _"I tried changing Sec-fetch-dest to "document" but the Browser restores it back to "empty"."_ - of course it does; the _point_ of these `Sec-` headers is that they are supposed to be SECure, trustworthy - they are by definition set automatically by the browser, and you can not overwrite them via code.

Comment: just clutching at straws.